# Como usar a mesma imagem 4 vezes ou mais no CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Gostaria de usar mais 3 vezes essa foto uma do lado da outra, só que não consigo multiplicar ela

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas para mim não fez sentido o que você precisa. O que exatamente quer fazer? Se é replicar a imagem na página, por quê apenas não replica o elemento do HTML que possui a imagem? Qual a relação co CSS no problema?

Comment: assim, eu não queria colocar a mesma imagem no html 4 vezes tendeu

Comment: acho que iria pesar no carregamento da pagina se fizesse isso, por isso que queria replicar ela pelo css, upando ela uma vez só

Comment: Mesmo pelo HTML, o navegador só irá requisitar a imagem apenas uma vez. Se a imagem faz parte do conteúdo da página, ela deverá ser um elemento `<img>`, caso contrário estará ferindo a semântica do seu código.

Comment: aaah, muito obrigado então Anderson, eu sabia que dava pra fazer assim, só que tinha receio do peso do site com mais imagens

Comment: Vai carregar a imagem do uma vez, ela vai ficar no cash do navegador, e sempre que vc chamar a imagem no html será a mesma imagem mesmo que 1000x